# Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

Im having a simple UI where i need a metamask connect button
but when i use this code i keep getting the
"Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!" error even though i have metamsk up an running in my browser

This is the code here:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
            var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            var option={from: accounts[0] };

        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        // Acccounts always exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
    const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
    const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');

ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getAccount();
});
async function getAccount() {
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
showAccount.innerHTML = account;

};
```

and this are the 2 buttons for account and to connect

```
<button class="enableEthereumButton">Enable Ethereum</button>
      <h2>Account: <span class="showAccount"></span></h2>
```

What do I need to do to make this work, i followed the metamask tutorial but they are written so bad, they are almost useless

Comment: Try to run this code inside a server such as Apache, nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use window for metamask access. You can try replacing your if with somthing like this.

```
if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
        await ethereum.enable();
        var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(accounts)

    } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
    }
}
```

The getAccount() function isn't neccesary as you should be able to pull everything from the web3.eth.* anyway.

Comment: if its not necessary why do you leave it in there?

Comment: Im referencing the async function at the bottom of your code snippet. getAccount() not getAccounts()